# Get last Sunday date in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, cron

I am using a **cron job** to generate weekly reports on my database. Basically, the report generation script is in PHP. I scheduled a daily cron job.

My week for the reporting starts on Sunday.

I only want the report generation script to generate report, for the previous week from previous Sunday through to previous Monday.

Take for example.

> Today is 4 March 2013. When the script runs, it should generate the
>   report for 24 Feb 2013 to 3 March 2013. Tomorrow, when the script
>   runs, it should also only run the report for 24 Feb 2013 to 3 March 2013.

How can I get last **Sunday's date**, automatically in my script?

Currently, I hard code using the following:

```
$startDate = strtotime("13 January 2013");

$strStartDate = date ("Y-m-d 00:00:00", $startDate);
$strEndDate = date ("Y-m-d 23:59:00", $startDate + (6*24*60*60));
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742820/php-how-to-get-previous-sunday-of-a-specific-date-in-the-past

Comment: Thanks, but how can I supply the 2nd parameter automatically? so, that the script can run automatically, where it will always return the last Sunday's date? For example, when the script runs today, it should return 24 Feb 2013.

Comment: What do you mean by `is it possible using function?` ???

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**For Last Sunday**

```
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime('last sunday'));
```

*Edited Answer:*

**For Last Last Sunday**

```
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime('last sunday -7 days'));
```

Comment: That will return 2013-03-03. But what I need is 2013-02-24. Maybe I should say last last Sunday?

Comment: @J K: the last sunday is March 3rd.

Comment: @zerkms I think he wants last last sunday

Comment: @zerkms, Sorry, I think I should have said that I need to get last last Sunday. Sumit, -7? But, the script will run every day, and it should always return last last Sunday, until the following week. For example, today it should return 2013-02-24. Tomorrow, it should also return 2013-02-24, and the day after, it should also return 2013-02-24.... Then on 10 Mac 2013, it will start to return 2013-03-03.

Comment: @JK use this `echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime('last sunday -7 days'));`

Comment: What if when the script runs on 11 March 2013? Will it return 2013-03-03? If yes, then this is the solution. :)

Comment: @JK yes on 11 March 2013, it will return 2013-03-03 (last sunday - 10 March and last last sunday 03 March)

Comment: Yes, I think this will work. But, just to be sure,... let's wait until tomorrow when I run the script to see if it will still return 2013-02-24. Thanks so much.

Comment: @JK why you don't change your system date to tomorrow?, you can test it by changing your system date. and many thanks..

Comment: Because I do not have this script readily available on a local server. It's all live on a production server. We will see tomorrow or the day after. Thanks so much.

Comment: J K, do you mean that you're developing and debugging on a live, production server? oh, my...

Answer (score 6):

```
<?php
$date=date("Y-m-d");
echo "Current Date : ".$date."<br>";
echo "last Sunday : ".date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date.'last sunday'));
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

### Introduction

To be honest am not sure what you mean by `is it possible using function?` but i guess you want a universal function but i think a simple class would also do the trick.

**Observation**

> it should also only run the report for 24 Feb 2013 to 3 March 2013.

Please note that from `Sunday 24 Feb 2013` to `Sunday 3 March 2013` is `8 days` and more than `1 weeks` which may result to `overlapping` data if you are ploting graphic or using it for analytic. I would suggest you limit it to `1 weeks` which is `Sunday, 24 Feb 2013` to  `Saturday, 2 March 2013`

Here is what i mean

```
// imagine today is Today is 4 March 2013
$today = DateTime::createFromFormat("d F Y", "4 March 2013");

$date = new PeroidDate();
vprintf("%s to %s", $date->getPeroid($today));
```

Output

```
 Sunday, 24 February 2013 to Saturday, 02 March 2013
```

### Other Examples

**Example 1**

```
// Example
$date = new PeroidDate();
print_r($date->getPeroid());
```

Output

```
stdClass Object
(
    [start] => Sunday, 31 March 2013
    [end] => Saturday, 06 April 2013
)

//or
Sunday, 31 March 2013
```

**Example 2**

Lets Imagine you want to get report for `before valentine period` that is "before February 14th"

```
print_r($date->getPeroid(new DateTime("2013-02-14")));
```

Output

```
stdClass Object
(
    [start] => Sunday, 03 February 2013
    [end] => Saturday, 09 February 2013
)
```

**Example 3**

Lets Imagine you want a range of date instead of a single range,eg. You want the date between `January 1`<sup>st</sup> and the `Current Time`(*Probably you want to use it for a select box*) then you use `PeroidDate::getBetween`

```
print_r($date->getBetween(new DateTime("2013-1-1"), new DateTime()));
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [start] => Sunday, 06 January 2013
            [end] => Saturday, 12 January 2013
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [start] => Sunday, 13 January 2013
            [end] => Saturday, 19 January 2013
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [start] => Sunday, 20 January 2013
            [end] => Saturday, 26 January 2013
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [start] => Sunday, 27 January 2013
            [end] => Saturday, 02 February 2013
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [start] => Sunday, 03 February 2013
            [end] => Saturday, 09 February 2013
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [start] => Sunday, 10 February 2013
            [end] => Saturday, 16 February 2013
        )

    [6] => stdClass Object
        (
            [start] => Sunday, 17 February 2013
            [end] => Saturday, 23 February 2013
        )

    [7] => stdClass Object
        (
            [start] => Sunday, 24 February 2013
            [end] => Saturday, 02 March 2013
        )

    [8] => stdClass Object
        (
            [start] => Sunday, 03 March 2013
            [end] => Saturday, 09 March 2013
        )

    [9] => stdClass Object
        (
            [start] => Sunday, 10 March 2013
            [end] => Saturday, 16 March 2013
        )

    [10] => stdClass Object
        (
            [start] => Sunday, 17 March 2013
            [end] => Saturday, 23 March 2013
        )

    [11] => stdClass Object
        (
            [start] => Sunday, 24 March 2013
            [end] => Saturday, 30 March 2013
        )

    [12] => stdClass Object
        (
            [start] => Sunday, 31 March 2013
            [end] => Saturday, 06 April 2013
        )

    [13] => stdClass Object
        (
            [start] => Sunday, 07 April 2013
            [end] => Saturday, 13 April 2013
        )

)
```

### Class Used

```
class PeroidDate {
    private $format;
    private $interval;

    function __construct() {
        $this->format = "l, d F Y";
        $this->interval = new DateInterval('P7D');
    }

    function setFormat($format) {
        $this->format = (string) $format;
    }

    function setInterval(DateInterval $format) {
        $this->format = $format;
    }

    function getPeroid(\Datetime $date = null) {
        $end = $date ?  : new DateTime();
        $end->modify("Last Sunday");

        print_r($end->format($this->format));

        $start = clone $end;
        $start->sub($this->interval);

        $end->modify("-1 day"); //

        return (object) array(
                "start" => $start->format($this->format),
                "end" => $end->format($this->format)
        );
    }

    function getBetween(Datetime $start = null, Datetime $end = null) {
        if ($start > $end)
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("`Start date` Must be greater than `End date`");

        if ($start === null) {
            $start = new DateTime();
            $start->modify("First Sunday of January");
        } else {
            $start->modify("First Sunday");
        }

        if ($end === null) {
            $end = new DateTime();
            $end->modify("Last Sunday of December");
        }

        $range = array();
        while ( $start < $end ) {
            $r = new stdClass();
            $r->start = $start->format($this->format);
            $start->add($this->interval);

            $tmp = clone $start;
            $tmp->modify("-1 day");

            $r->end = $tmp->format($this->format);
            $range[] = $r;
        }
        return $range;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this code.

```
echo date('m/d/Y', strtotime('last Sunday'));
```

You can get last Sunday according to today.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$sun =  date('Y-m-d',strtotime('last sunday'));
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last Sunday', strtotime($sun)));
```

it will return `2013-02-24`

Answer (score 1):

Since this question is tagged also MySql, if you need to calculate the interval in a query you could use something like this:

```
SELECT
  '2013-03-04' - INTERVAL (WEEKDAY('2013-03-04')+1) % 7 DAY - INTERVAL 1 WEEK start_date,
  '2013-03-04' - INTERVAL (WEEKDAY('2013-03-04')+1) % 7 DAY end_date
```

Then to generate a report you can just use CURDATE():

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_tables
WHERE  ... AND
       report_date BETWEEN
         CURDATE() - INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(CURDATE())+1) % 7 DAY - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
         AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(CURDATE())+1) % 7 DAY
```